# Styling a menu item to blue color and larger font size in Joomla 3.4.5

Tags: css

I went to the Manage menu->Menu item, link css style and added

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav-right> a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav-right> a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav-right> a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

for that menu item, but it did not change the color to blue or increase its font size.

How can I change the menu item's font color to blue and increase its font size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This field is for adding CSS classes, not inline styles.

In that field add class, for example `blue-item`.

Then in your template CSS file add this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav-right> a.blue-item,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav-right> a.blue-item:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav-right> a.blue-item:active {
  color: #0000FF;
  font-size: 200%;
}
```